# I am not able to make the favourite and unfavourite view work in Django application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to implement some favourite function in my application. but when using the get_objects_or_404, I am getting this weird error.

I am trying to make a user click an icon to add a product to the favourite list, in the tutorial I was following, I noticed that it was only possible when he has the post detail, so he only added access to click the icon to add the post to favourite on the post detail page, so he was able to do something like "post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)" while passing the id into the request. but the case is different in my case whereby I have all of the products on a page, and I am not utilizing a product detail page, so I wan a user to as well be able to click the icon on the products page

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourite', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def my_favourite_list(request):
    user = request.user
    favourite_posts = user.is_favourite.all()
    context = {"favourite_posts":favourite_posts}
    return render(request, "core/my-fav-products.html", context)

@login_required
def Products(request):
    title = "All Products"

    products = Product.objects.annotate(
        favourited_by_user=Count(Case(
            When(
                is_favourite=request.user,
                then=1
            ),
            default=0,
            output_field=BooleanField(),
        )),
    ).order_by('-id')

    my_products = Product.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-id')

    context = {"products":products, "my_products":my_products, "title":title}

    return render(request, 'core/products.html', context)

def change_favourite(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if Product.objects.filter(pk=pk, is_favourite=request.user).exists():
            product.is_favourite.remove(request.user)
        else:
            product.is_favourite.add(request.user)
    return redirect('product')
```

products.html

```
{% for product in products %}
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" style="height: 200px!important;" src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-title mb-3">
                <span>{{product.name}}</span>
                <span style="float: right;">
                    <form action="{% url 'add-favourite' product.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline-flex;">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit">
                            {% if product.favourited_by_user %}
                                <i style="font-size: 22px!important;" class="fas fa-star m-r-10"></i>
                            {% else %}
                                <i style="font-size: 22px!important;" class="far fa-star m-r-10"></i>
                            {% endif %}
                        </button>
                    </form>
                    <a href="{% url 'edit-product' product.id %}"><i style="font-size: 22px!important;" class="zmdi zmdi-edit m-r-10"></i></a>
                    <a href="{% url 'delete-product' product.id %}"><i style="font-size: 22px!important;" class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i></a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text">
                <span>Price: {{product.price}}</span>
                <span style="float: right;">Quantity: {{product.quantity}}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That means that there are *multiple* of these elements, this will happen if your database has multiple elemnes due to the `get_object_or_404(Product)` that does not filter on anything like `pk`, etc.

Comment: If you want a list try using [`get_list_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404). Although I notice you just get it the line below. You don't even use the variable `product` just remove the line `product = get_object_or_404(Product)` then.

Comment: Can you please explain *what* you aim to do, and share (relevant parts of) your models.

Comment: I am trying to make a user click an icon to add a product to the favourite list, in the tutorial i was following,  i noticed that it was only possible when he has the post detail, so he was only add access to click the icon to add the post to favourite on the post detail page, so he was able to do something like "post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)" while passing the id into the request. but the case is different in my case whereby i have all of the products on a page, and i am not utilizing a product detail page, so i wan a user to as well be able to click the icon on the products page.

Comment: @coderboy: then you should make a separate view to handle the click, and redirect back to the list page.

Comment: please is there a way i can make the user click the icon to add a product to a favourite list while on the product page which has a list of products instead of having to create a  product detail page to do that.

Comment: @coderboy Just have the view redirect the user (after adding to favourite as you want) as Willem says. No need to display anything.

Comment: @coderboy: you should also make a POST request, since you change an entity in the database, and a POST request normally does *not* render the page if it was successful to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, please could you provide a answer in the answer section, I don't understand what you really meant.

Comment: @coderboy If you would have shared (relevant parts of) your models (as Willem stated) to the question you would have already received an answer by now.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, please explain better how i should make it a POST request. because it is not a form and I ddon't really understand how i should go abou that. Thanks.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat okay, i will do that.

Comment: I have edited the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly fix your view `Products`. (also ideally function names should be in `snake_case`, meaning it should be named `products`).

```
from django.db.models import Case, Count, BooleanField, When

def Products(request):
    title = "All Products"
    products = Product.objects.annotate(
        favourited_by_user=Count(Case(
            When(
                is_favourite=request.user,
                then=1
            ),
            output_field=BooleanField(),
        )),
    ).order_by('-id')
    my_products = Product.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-id')

    context = {"products":products, "my_products":my_products, "title":title}

    return render(request, 'core/products.html', context)
```

Now write another view for the favouriting logic:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect


def change_favourite(request, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if Product.objects.filter(pk=pk, is_favourite=request.user).exists():
            product.is_favourite.remove(request.user)
        else:
            product.is_favourite.add(request.user)
    return redirect('view-name-of-products-list')
```

Now add a url for this view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('add-to-favourite/<int:pk>/', change_favourite, name='add-favourite'),
    ...
]
```

Now in your html simply put those buttons in a form:

```
<form action="{% url 'add-favourite' product.pk %}" method="post">
    <button type="submit">{% if product.favourited_by_user %}Un-favourite Product{% else %}Favourite Product{% endif %}</button>
</form>
```

Style the buttons as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer sir.

Comment: it seems like the answer doesn't work Sir. I have made the necessary amendments but after clicking the star, it doesn't change from regular star to solid star to show that it has been favourited.

Comment: is there a way i can check if there is any way the product has been favourited for that user and also have a list for all users to check their favourited products.

Comment: @coderboy Keep only the text `{% if product.favourited_by_user %}Un-favourite Product{% else %}Favourite Product{% endif %}` for now does that work properly? Also it should be a submit button not an anchor like your question had.

Comment: it does not sir.

Comment: it remains the same even after clicking.

Comment: I will edit the question to the recent update now.

Comment: @coderboy Slight mistake in the annotation. Fixed it, should work now. (remove `default=0,`)

Comment: okay sir, i will do that now. Hpw can i get the list of a particular users favurite please. what query can i use for that please.

Comment: @coderboy You set `related_name='favourite'` that means for an instance of `User` you can write `user.favourite.all()` to get all the favourited products.

Comment: I have removed the default=0, it still the same result sir.

Comment: do you mean User.favourite.all() or user.favourite.all()

Comment: it all works now. I have been able to get the favourite list of each user

Comment: the only issue now is that, after favourting a product, the mark doesn't change to unfavourite. what is the issue there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229568/discussion-between-abdul-aziz-barkat-and-coderboy).